# writerow in CSV file problems

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, row

I'm a beginner in Python, and I'm trying to extract data from the web and display it in a table :

```
# import libraries
import urllib2  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import csv  
from datetime import datetime

quote_page = 'http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND' 
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)  
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser') 
name_box = soup.find('h1', attrs={'class': 'name'})
name = name_box.text.strip() 
print name
price_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'price'})  
price = price_box.text  
print price  

with open('index.csv', 'a') as csv_file:  
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow([name, price, datetime.now()])
```

this is a very basic code that extract data from bloomberg and display it in an csv file. 
It should display the name in a column, the price in an other one and the date in the third one. 
But actually it copy all this data in the first row :  [Result of the index.csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UT7g5.png) .

Am I missing something with my code?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: your csv does have three columns. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: It looks like the CSV file is perfect (that is, well done with the Python code!). The problem is however you are importing it into your spreadsheet program. How are you doing that?

Comment: The problem was that Excel did not allow a column to each file because I did not use the Text Import Wizard. 
Now my problem is the one describe by Joseph Bywater .

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

> In computing, a comma-separated values (CSV) file stores tabular data (numbers and text) in plain text. Each line of the file is a data record. Each record consists of one or more fields, separated by commas. The use of the comma as a field separator is the source of the name for this file format.

The problem isn't related to your Python code! Your script actually writes the plain text file with the fields separated by commas. It is your csv file viewer which doesn't take commas as separators. You should check in the preferences of your csv file viewer.

Comment: I was using Excel and I resolve my problem with your precious help ! 
For anyone reading this in the future : 
Go to Data and select  text to columns under data tools then select delimited and hit next. Then select comma as the delimiter and hit finish.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you are importing your CSV into Excel that it isn't being interpreted right. When I imported it into Excel, I noticed that the comma in the "2,337.58" is messing up the CSV data, putting the ,337.58" into a column of it's own. When you import the data into excel, you should get a popup that will ask how the data is represented. You should pick the delimited option and then select delimiter: comma. Finally, click finish.

[image: Importing CSV]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, for your detailed answer. 
Is there a way to fix the " "2,337.58" problem ?

Comment: @VI55:  In step 2 of the import wizard do you have the text qualifier set to double quotes (`"`)?  The reason Joseph Bywater is having trouble with the second column is that the column starts with a space rather than a quote.  `S&P 500 Index, "2,337.58",2017-02-15 14:02:55.217830` should be `S&P 500 Index,"2,337.58",2017-02-15 14:02:55.217830`.  When the quote is not the first character in the field it is not treated as a quoted field.  (Quoting allows you have delimiters in your data that aren't treated as delimiters.)

Comment: @VI55: From the image you posted of the results of your Excel import I think it's likely that you don't have an extra space in your data because it's not in the image.  It's more likely that you don't have the text qualifier set to double quotes.